# How to minimize forecast error with fmin?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I'm trying to minimize forecast error by choosing the right "fall out rate" (r). I'm still fairly new to Pandas and brand new to SciPy. Please help!

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import fmin

data = pd.DataFrame({'Division': [1,2,3]*3,
                     'Month': ['May','May','May','June','June','Jun','Jul','Jul','Jul'],
                     'Definite_Units':[8]*9,
                     'Maybe_Units':[3,2,1]*3,
                     'Actually_Shipped_Units':[9]*9})

p = lambda r,x,y: x+y*r
e = lambda r,x,y,z: abs(1-(p(x,y,r)/z))

x = div_data['Definite_Units'].sum
y = div_data['Maybe_Units'].sum
z = div_data['Actually_Shipped_Units'].sum

for d in range(1,4):
    r0 = 1
    div_data = data['Division']=d
    x = div_data['Definite_Units'].sum()
    y = div_data['Maybe_Units'].sum()
    z = div_data['Actually_Shipped_Units'].sum()
    t = fmin(e,r0,args=(x,y,z))
    print d, t
```

I want an r for each division that minimizes e.

So in this case my outputs should be:

- Division 1: r = 0.33, e = 0
- Division 2: r = 0.50, e = 0
- Division 3: r = 1.00, e = 0

Comment: So what's the question...

Comment: @sascha how do I set this up to get an r for each division that minimizes e?

Comment: i understand now that fmin requires args to be in an array and I am working on that.

Comment: @sascha I did a lot of work on my code and posted a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152316/why-am-i-getting-incorrect-results-from-scipy-optimize-fmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I learned a few things about fmin during this project:

-Arguments must be in array format so I made the return_array helper function.

-The variable you want to optimize must be listed first in the function you want to minimize. So for me it had to be e(r,c,u,s), not e(c,u,s,r).

```
#calculate new fall out rates with fmin
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import fmin

data = pd.DataFrame({'DIV': [1,2,3]*3,
                     'MONTH': ['May','May','May','June','June','Jun','Jul','Jul','Jul'],
                     'C':[8]*9,
                     'U':[3,2,1]*3,
                     'S':[9]*9})

data.to_csv(r'C:\Users\mbabski\Documents\Unit Plan Summer 2016\data_test.csv')

def return_array(x):
    return x.values

def mape(c,u,s,r): #returns an array of line level Mean Absolute Percentage Errors
    p = c + u * r #calculates the forecasted number number
    m = abs(1.0-(p/s)) #calculates the MAPE at the line level
    return m

def e(r,c,u,s): #calculates average of the MAPEs
    return np.mean(mape(c,u,s,r)) 

for d in range(1,4):
    div_data = data[data.DIV==d]
    c = return_array(div_data.C)
    u = return_array(div_data.U)
    s = return_array(div_data.S)
    r0 = [[1.0]]
    t = fmin(e,r0,args=(c,u,s))
    print 'r:',t
```

> Optimization terminated successfully.
>            Current function value: 0.000011
>            Iterations: 16
>            Function evaluations: 32
>  r: [ 0.33330078] 
> Optimization terminated successfully.
>            Current function value: 0.000000
>            Iterations: 15
>            Function evaluations: 30 
> r: [ 0.5] 
> Optimization terminated successfully.
>            Current function value: 0.000000
>            Iterations: 10
>            Function evaluations: 20 
> r: [ 1.]