# Why am I getting incorrect results from scipy.optimize.fmin?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, optimization, scipy

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import fmin

data = pd.DataFrame({'DIV': [1,2,3]*3,
                     'MONTH': ['May','May','May','June','June','Jun','Jul','Jul','Jul'],
                     'C':[8]*9,
                     'U':[3,2,1]*3,
                     'S':[9]*9})

data.to_csv(r'C:\Users\mbabski\Documents\Unit Plan Summer 2016\data_test.csv')

def return_array(x):
    return x.values

def mape(c,u,s,r): #returns an array of line level Mean Absolute Percentage Errors
    p = c + u * r
    m = abs(1.0-(p/s))
    return m

def e(c,u,s,r): #calculates average of the MAPEs
    return np.mean(mape(c,u,s,r))

for d in range(1,4):
    div_data = data[data.DIV==d]
    c = return_array(div_data.C)
    u = return_array(div_data.U)
    s = return_array(div_data.S)
    r0 = [[1.0]]
    t = fmin(e,r0,args=(c,u,s))
    print 'r:',t
```

> Optimization terminated successfully.
>            Current function value: 0.000000
>            Iterations: 29
>            Function evaluations: 58 
> r: [-69.] 
> Optimization terminated successfully.
>            Current function value: 0.000000
>            Iterations: 29
>            Function evaluations: 58 
> r: [-70.] 
> Optimization terminated successfully.
>            Current function value: 0.000000
>            Iterations: 29
>            Function evaluations: 58 
> r: [-71.]

Why am I getting r = -69, -70, and -71?
I should be getting r = 0.333, 0.555, and 0.999 with this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scipy.optimize.fmin` will pass the value it is trying to minimize as the first argument to the function. If you rewrite your function as

```
def e(r,c,u,s): #calculates average of the MAPEs
    return np.mean(mape(c,u,s,r))
```

You get the correct results

```
for d in range(1,4):
    div_data = data[data.DIV==d]
    c = return_array(div_data.C)
    u = return_array(div_data.U)
    s = return_array(div_data.S)
    r0 = [[1.0]]
    t = fmin(e,r0,args=(c,u,s))
    print 'r:',t
```

> ```
> Optimization terminated successfully.
>          Current function value: 0.000011
>          Iterations: 16
>          Function evaluations: 32
> r: [ 0.33330078]
> Optimization terminated successfully.
>          Current function value: 0.000000
>          Iterations: 15
>          Function evaluations: 30
> r: [ 0.5]
> Optimization terminated successfully.
>          Current function value: 0.000000
>          Iterations: 10
>          Function evaluations: 20
> r: [ 1.]
> ```